# PHP explode and sort

Tags: php, sorting, explode

I need to sort an exploded string to write into database.

With the code down below it works, but I was not able to detect the summary of arrays outside the foreach loop.

So `$terms[0].$terms[1].$terms[2]` was not correct.

Cause as example `$terms[0].$terms[1].$terms[2].$terms[3]` was required for 4 terms in string.

How could that be solved?

```
$terms = explode(";", "banana;apple;lemon");

sort($terms);

$length = count($terms);

for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {

$terms[$x] = $terms[$x].'; ';
}

$sorted_terms = $terms[0].$terms[1].$terms[2]; // <<< should changed dynamically

$sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO mydatabase (terms) VALUES ('$sorted_terms')");
```

Comment: you have implode function wich is the opposite of explode. It makes a string out of an array, using the specified glue. And please be careful with sql injection...

Comment: Although I don't know your exact use case, storing more than one atomic value (term) in a a field is rarely a good idea as it violates 1NF.  Using a separate table for your terms might be the better long term solution and it would make the current problem irrelevant.

Comment: thanks Zyigh. Have solved it with    $terms = "banana;apple;lemon";
     $sorted_terms = explode(";", $terms); 
     sort($sorted_terms, SORT_STRING); 
     $sorted_terms = implode(";", $sorted_terms);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use string concatenation.
Use $terms1 as string in for loop.

```
$terms1 = "";
$terms = explode(";", "banana;apple;lemon");
sort($terms);
$length = count($terms);
for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
$terms1 .= $terms[$x].'; ';
}

//$sorted_terms = $terms[0].$terms[1].$terms[2];
//$sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO mydatabase (terms) VALUES ('$sorted_terms')");
$sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO mydatabase (terms) VALUES ('$terms1')");
```

Comment: This works; but `implode` does the same thing with far less code.

Comment: Yes Martin sure, but this is reply for his understanding in question asked above "but I was not able to detect the summary of arrays outside the foreach loop."

Comment: It works also thanks, but have solved it with implode. Code looks like cleaner :)

Comment: @walker2k if you solved it with implode then this answer is not the right answer because this answer doesn't use implode.

Comment: @Martin Kuldepp solves it exactly with my code in question. So that answer was for me the correct one.
That i've been used implode at the end, doesn't change the content from question.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) which is an exact opposite of `explode` and intended for just this sort of thing.

```
$terms = explode(";", "banana;apple;lemon");
sort($terms);
$sorted_terms = implode(";", $terms);

//$sorted_terms = "apple;banana;lemon";
```

## Edit:

As you're using procedural MySQLi for your data entry you should also use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to limit SQL injection into your database. I know it may not apply to your current work but it's best practise to get into - short of actually using Prepared Statements.

so:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO mydatabase (terms) 
       VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $sorted_terms)."')");
```

## Using [Prepared Statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection) instead is very highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$sorted_terms = implode(';', $terms);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Why does the OP want dots/periods instead of the `;` as specified in their question?

Comment: Why? It's not clear whether OP wants `;` or `.` so I'm going by the given example.

Comment: OP states: `$terms[$x].'; ';` . OP at no point states they want `"."`. You may be getting confused with the [PHP String Concatenation Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)